# How does StackExchange support subdomains?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, subdomains

**Background:**

I have read an answer to the question : [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network). It is mentioned that `IIS 8.0` is used as a WebServer.

**Question:**

In IIS, If one wants to set up subdomains, one will have to create a new website with the subdomain.

How has StackExchange addressed this issue as they have so many subdomains? Have they created these many websites using IIS like this:

http://meta.stackexchange.com

http://webapps.stackexchange.com

http://gis.stackexchange.com

http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

http://ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Q&A sites are the wildcard binding in IIS (of which you can only have one), so anything hitting *:80 hits out multi-tenancy application pool. Beyond that we're looking `Host` header to determine which theme, database, etc. you are given on the request.